# How do I get browsers to trust self-signed certificates for testing? Website address is slightly different than fully qualified domain name

Tags: iis, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a website that is being configured with SSL, and I am using a self-signed certificate for testing purposes, for now.  The machine is running Windows 2008 R2 with IIs 7.5 and Apache Tomcat 5.5.

The problem is FireFox is gives the error that the connection is untrusted because it's a self-signed certificate and it also says that the site is using an invalid security certificate.  I tried importing the certificate into Firefox, to remedy the situation, and it did not help.  However, with IE, exporting the certificate from IIS and importing it into the browser's Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store permitted IE to trust the self-signed certificate.

It's important to note that the server's fully qualified domain name is webdev.dev.mysite.com, whereas the website address is webdev.mysite.com and I've had no problems with the site under HTTP.  And with the help of the site [here](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/04/16/setting-up-ssl-made-easy.aspx), I setup the self-signed certificate such that it's name is webdev.mysite.com.

How can I get Firefox to trust the self-signed certificate?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this page should help you:

In FireFox, go to Tools -> Options
Click the Advanced Tab, then the View Certificates button
Go to the Servers tab and press the Add Exception button

Note: It might depend on your version of Firefox

Source: www.poweradmin.com/help/sslhints/FireFox.aspx